# CSV Parsing difficulty

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file with multiple comma seperated values each enclosed in "". One of the fields has multiple comma seperated values enclosed in "". For eg. "test1","Test2","test0,test4,test5". Can i replace the 3rd field with multiple values with a text of my choice? I am facing an error while parsing this csv data into Json format.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Expecting to replace "test0,test4,test5" with a string enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Please add code which you have created

Comment: No code created yet, just looking out for the logic on how can this be achieved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Python has a CSV parser module. You should use it to parse your CSV file. You can then generate a JSON representation.

Comment: Also, if you have not written any code, how is it possible that you are "facing an error"?

Answer (score -1):

This could do the trick for you:

```
with open("stack.csv", 'r') as f:
    with open('new_file.csv', 'w') as f2:
        rows = f.readlines()
        for row in rows:
            new_row = []
            for col in row.split('","'):
                if ',' in col:
                    for part in col.split(","):
                        new_row.append(part)
                else:
                    new_row.append(col)
            f2.write(str(new_row)[1:-1] + '\n')
```

Maybe not the most Pythonic way of writing the code but it should do the trick.